# Nav bar collapse menu is not working on mobile and table viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have and issue with bootstrap3 `navbar-menu` on a smaller `viewport`. When I go to response mode in inspector and click on a `hamburger` icon I don't see any interaction, debug tool is not showing any error, and I have all standard bootstrap3 `navbar` `collapse` class code to support smaller `viewport`, I'm just overlooking something.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'index' %}"><img src="static/img/SNYClogo.png" height=50 width=110></a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul id="navbar" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="{% url 'index' %}">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Apartments</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <li><a id="logout" href="/accounts/logout">Logout</a></li>
        {% else %}
            <li class="pull-right" id="showlogin"><a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info round">GET STARTED</button></a></li>
        {% endif %}
            </ul>
    </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

Can someone please check this [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/copser/ws4z63Lu/), and inspect mine code.

Comment: here, sorry about that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give `.navbar` id to parent `div` not `ul`.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="..." height=50 width=110></a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="{% url 'index' %}">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Apartments</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <li><a id="logout" href="/accounts/logout">Logout</a></li>
            {% else %}
                <li class="pull-right" id="showlogin"><a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info round">GET STARTED</button></a></li>
            {% endif %}
                </ul>
        </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ws4z63Lu/7/)**

Comment: @PetarP glad to help. Don't forget to mark it answer by clicking on right symbol. When you can.